# PHP CURL saving multiple XML url links?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to save 3 XML url links to write to local xml cache copy of them. But 2 of the XML url links with parameters passed after ? aren't saving at all ?

only allteams.xml gets saved into multicache folder while other 2 urls don't get saved ?

there must be a better way to do this ?

```
<?php

$urls=array(
'http://remotedomain.com/api/team.xml?id=12',
'http://remotedomain.com/api/allteams.xml',
'http://remotedomain.com/api/allmembers.xml?limit=1000&id=12');

$save_to='multicache/';

$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    $g=$save_to.basename($url);
    if(!is_file($g)){
        $conn[$i]=curl_init($url);
        $fp[$i]=fopen ($g, "w");
        curl_setopt ($conn[$i], CURLOPT_FILE, $fp[$i]);
        curl_setopt ($conn[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER ,0);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,60);
        curl_multi_add_handle ($mh,$conn[$i]);
    }
}
do {
    $n=curl_multi_exec($mh,$active);
}
while ($active);
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$conn[$i]);
    curl_close($conn[$i]);
    fclose ($fp[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how about some low-tech solution:

```
foreach ($urls as $url)
{   
    copy($url, $save_to . basename($url));
}
```

No curl, just some basic PHP streams.

I'm not sure about that `is_file()` business, if you want to check that the file doesn't exist, use [`file_exists()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).